# Preventing ViewDidUnload during Low Memory?

Tags: ios, memory, uiimagepickercontroller, viewdidload

In my app I have a UIImagePicker and it keeps throwing up a Memory Warning Level 1 (the lowest). Then it keeps messing up my app because it is calling the viewdidunload or viewwillunload. Is there any way to prevent these methods from getting called when I am presenting the UIImagePickerController so that my ViewDidLoad won't get called again?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the problem exactly? What are you doing in `viewDidLoad` that you don't want to be executed more than once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a **BOOL** variable, such as **`warning`**.

```
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning 
{
    warning = YES;    
}
- (void)viewDidUnload 
{
    if ( warning )
        return;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure why someone else down voted your answer and didn't explain why but I up voted it. My answer also fixed my issue but I will give the answer to you since I could also do this. Would you mind up voting my answer below?

Answer (score 0):

I found my own answer!
This fixed it for me:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [imageView setImage:image];
}
```

Comment: Why would someone down vote my answer when in the end this fixed my memory warning issue?

Answer (score 0):

Set a flag in didReceiveMemoryWarning and check the flag in  viewDidLoad & viewDidUnload